# How to properly set up Vuex in a Vuejs application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vite

I'm creating a Vuejs application and I want to use Vuex.

But I couldn't add the Vuex store.

This is my code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userData: "USER!"
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  },
  getters: {

  }
})

export default store
```

I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue.js?v=52de2cee' does not provide an export named 'default'

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
const app = createApp(App)
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { store } from '@/store/users'

app.use(router)
app.use(Vuex)

app.mount('#app')
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

The first block of code you show is for Vue 2, which won't work in Vue 3. And Vue 3 requires Vuex 4.

To setup Vuex 4 in a Vue 3 app:

1. Install Vuex 4:

   ```sh
   npm i -S vuex@next
   ```
2. Update the store to use the [Vuex 4 `createStore` API](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) (which creates a plugin for `app.use()` in the next step):

   ```js
   // @/store.js
   import { createStore } from 'vuex'

   export default createStore({
     state: {
       userData: "USER!"
     },
     mutations: {

     },
     actions: {

     },
     getters: {

     }
   })
   ```
3. Update the main script to install the store with `app.use()`:

   ```js
   import { createApp } from 'vue'
   import store from '@/store'

   const app = createApp(App)
   app.use(store)
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuex-vite-typescript-starter?file=src%2Fstore.ts)